# Unable to install apache superset

Tags: pip, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04, apache-superset

Unable to install apache superset.

I was installing from this link for python https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html

Run command `pip3 install superset`. 
Displays Error regarding pandas library version 0.25

After downgrading pandas to version 0.22. Shows an error like this

`raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (Flask 0.12.4 (/home/drax/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('Flask>=1.0'), {'Flask-JWT-Extended'})`

Answer (score 1):

https://pypi.org/project/superset/

Superset has moved to apache-superset, as of **0.34.0** onwards, please **pip install apache-superset**

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of old versions in your `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`. To install `superset` you need to upgrade them. You can allow `pip` to upgrade everything:

```
pip install --upgrade --user superset
```

But my recommendation is to create a new empty Python virtual environment:

```
virtualenv superset
source superset/bin/activate
pip install superset
```

Comment: There are two things happened while I use your recommended things ------1.gives ERROR: flask-jwt-extended 3.22.0 has requirement Flask>=1.0, but you'll have flask 0.12.4 which is incompatible.-------- 2. when I tried to run superset db upgrade it gives from pandas.core.common import _maybe_box_datetimelike
ImportError: cannot import name '_maybe_box_datetimelike'